# python: finding input to output paths in networkX

Tags: python, path, network-programming, bioinformatics, networkx

EDIT: Now looking on how to calculate # of "looping paths" per node

As the title says, I'm trying to make a function that calculates the number of "signal paths" for any node in a network. A signal path for a node is a path from one of multiple inputs to one of multiple outputs that the node is a part of. I'm using an algorithm someone already made called [all_simple_paths](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/development/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.simple_paths.all_simple_paths.html), which is a generator which returns every path from an input to an output.

However, even though my code looks right, I'm getting incorrect results. Here's the function:

```
def signal_path_counter(G, inputs, outputs, node):
    c = 0
    paths = []
    for out in outputs:
        for i in inputs:
            for path in all_simple_paths(G, i, out):
                paths.append(path)
    for path in paths:
        for n in path:
            if(node == n):
                c += 1
    return c
```

Here's the input data:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
G=nx.DiGraph()
molecules = ["CD40L", "CD40", "NF-kB", "XBP1", "Pax5", "Bach2", "Irf4", "IL-4", "IL-4R", "STAT6", "AID", "Blimp1", "Bcl6", "ERK", "BCR", "STAT3", "Ag", "STAT5", "IL-21R", "IL-21", "IL-2", "IL-2R"]
Bcl6 = [("Bcl6", "Bcl6"), ("Bcl6", "Blimp1"), ("Bcl6", "Irf4")]
STAT5 = [("STAT5", "Bcl6")]
IL_2R = [("IL-2R", "STAT5")]
IL_2 = [("IL-22", "IL-2R")]
BCR = [("BCR", "ERK")]
Ag = [("Ag", "BCR")]
CD40L = [("CD40L", "CD40")]
CD40 = [("CD40", "NF-B")]
NF_B = [("NF-B", "Irf4"), ("NF-B", "AID")]
Irf4 = [("Irf4", "Bcl6"), ("Irf4", "Pax5"), ("Irf4", "Irf4"), ("Irf4", "Blimp1")]
ERK = [("ERK", "Bcl6"), ("ERK", "Blimp1"), ("ERK", "Pax5")]
STAT3 = [("STAT3", "Blimp1")]
IL_21 = [("IL-21", "IL-21R")]
IL_21R = [("IL-21R", "STAT3")]
IL_4R = [("IL-4R", "STAT6")]
STAT6 = [("STAT6", "AID"), ("STAT6", "Bcl6")]
Bach2 = [("Bach2", "Blimp1")]
IL_4 = [("IL-4", "IL-4R")]
Blimp1 = [("Blimp1", "Bcl6"), ("Blimp1", "Bach2"), ("Blimp1", "Pax5"), ("Blimp1", "AID"), ("Blimp1", "Irf4")]
Pax5 = [("Pax5", "Pax5"), ("Pax5", "AID"), ("Pax5", "Bcl6"), ("Pax5", "Bach2"), ("Pax5", "XBP1"), ("Pax5", "ERK"), ("Pax5", "Blimp1")]
edges = Bcl6 + STAT5 + IL_2R + IL_2 + BCR + Ag + CD40L + CD40 + NF_B + Irf4 + 
ERK + STAT3 + IL_21 + IL_21R + IL_4R + STAT6 + Bach2 + IL_4 + Blimp1 + Pax5
G.add_nodes_from(molecules)
G.add_edges_from(edges)
sources = ["Ag", "CD40L", "IL-2", "IL-21", "IL-4"]
targets = ["XBP1", "AID"]
```

Visual representation of the input network [here](http://journals.plos.org/ploscompbiol/article/figure/image?size=large&id=10.1371/journal.pcbi.1004696.g002).

The function call that gives incorrect result of 0:

```
print(signal_path_counter(G, sources, targets, "IL-2R"))
```

Comment: So no, if you look at the visual representation of the graph, the sources and targets are just input and output nodes, which we use to calculate an X number of paths to get from any input to any output. IL-2R is a node that's on the way, and I want to get a counter of how many times IL-2R appears in these input to output paths. This count is what I'm returning in my function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your typo is in this line:

```
IL_2 = [("IL-22", "IL-2R")]
```

It should be

```
IL_2 = [("IL-2", "IL-2R")]
```

---

There are some things that can be done with your code to make it more "pythonic".  Iterating over multiple combinations can be done more cleanly using [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/533917/2966723), which would replace the loop over `out` and over `i` with

```
for input, output in itertools.product(inputs, outputs):
    for path in all_simple_paths(G, input, output):
        paths.append(...)
```

Also rather than building up paths and then looping through `paths` to test if the node is in it, do the test directly rather than appending to `paths`:

```
for input, output in itertools.product(inputs, outputs):
    for path in all_simple_paths(G, input, output):
        if node in path:
            c += 1
```

Even for this code, I think it could be made cleaner using a `Counter`.  Basically, if you're ever doing `variable += 1`, or appending elements to a list while iterating, there's often a "more pythonic" way to do it.

I am concerned about how well this algorithm will scale for larger networks.  Finding all paths is expensive.  It may be better to start from `node` and build all paths from  `node` to `outputs` and all paths from `inputs` to `node`.  Then convert each path into a set [the conversion into sets makes the next step faster].  Then go through the in and out paths and see if they have any intersection.  If not, then you've got a path through `node`.

This would significantly reduce the number of paths you end up having to consider (and likely the length of the paths as well).

Comment: Thank you for the idea on how to optimize this. Right now, I'm writing a paper that will only be using 2 networks of this size, so luckily for me efficiency isn't a huge issue.

Comment: Followup question, another value I need to calculate for every node is "feedback loops", which means how many times the node appears in a looping-path. Is there a built in algorithm for this?

Comment: I would need to know a bit more what exactly a "looping path" is.  I can think of a couple possible definitions...

Comment: It's a path that can be repeated, aka a path that results in a loop. Like node A -> node B -> node Z -> node A, if these paths existed, this would be considered a loop. Input/output isn't considers here obviously because there's nothing leading to input and nothing going out from output.

Comment: can the looping path have more than one cycle within it, or can it only repeat node A?

Comment: The relevant paper to the program I'm writing: https://bmcbioinformatics.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1471-2105-7-515

Comment: I believe it can have more than one "cycle" in it. I'm not to sure myself.

Comment: If a feedback loop does not allow cycles, then just look for a simple path from a node to one of its inputs.  If `1->2->3->4->5->3->1` counts as a feedback loop, then it's hard to figure out what to do.  Because `1->2->3->1` would also be a loop, as would `1->2->3->4->5->3->4->5->3->4->5->3->4->5->3->1`.  So I imagine they probably want to exclude loops within loops.  But the paper doesn't seem to make it clear.

Comment: Going to look into it then post a separate question later if I can't figure it out, thanks for your help.